# Error: unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJs. When getting data from controller.js to service.js, I am getting the error. Below is the code used:

//controller.js

```
 angular.module('testApp.controllers', []).
    controller('testController', function ($scope, testAPIService, $timeout, $window, $location, $anchorScroll, $http) {

 $scope.show = function() {

     testAPIService.getDataSummary().success(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    }).error(function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        });

    }
    });
```

In Service.js

```
angular.module('testApp.services', []).
factory('testAPIService', ['$http', function ($http) {
 var testAPIService = {};
 testAPIService.getDataSummary = function () {
        var request = {
            url: urlBase + 'GetDataSummary',
            method: 'Get',
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        return $http(request);
    };
  return testAPIService;
}]);
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: In your `testAPIService` factory, where does the `testAPIService` object come from?

Comment: Always include full text of the error, including stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two different modules:

- The first module `testApp.controllers` is created when you create the controller
- Another module `testApp.services` is created when you create the service.

So the controller and the service are never part of the same module!

Try attaching to the same `testApp` module as follows:

**app.js**

```
// With [] means to create a new module.
angular.module('testApp', []);
```

**controller.js**

```
// Without [] means to retrieve an existing module.
angular.module('testApp').
controller('testController', function($scope, testAPIService, $timeout, $window, $location, $anchorScroll, $http) {

  $scope.show = function() {

    testAPIService.getDataSummary().success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

    }).error(function(response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    });

  }
});
```

**service.js**

```
// Without [] means to retrieve an existing module.
angular.module('testApp').
factory('testAPIService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var testAPIService = {};
  testAPIService.getDataSummary = function() {
    var request = {
      url: urlBase + 'GetDataSummary',
      method: 'Get',
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    return $http(request);
  };
  return testAPIService;
}]);
```

**index.html**

And change your `ng-app` directive to point to the `testApp` module

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
```

Comment: Hi @matthew Cawley. sorry missed the return statement in the code. It was there, I had missed it while posting it here. I have updated the existing code

Comment: Also, if i refresh the page after the error, then when the method is hit - no error is shown. Only when the method is hit in the first time, this error is shown, and no data is returned

Comment: Hi @Matthew Cawley. I have updated the code as per your logic. I have made the changes in the existing code block which i have given. But still the same error

Comment: Are you definitely calling `angular.module('testApp')` rather than `angular.module('testApp',[])` when declaring the service and the controller? The lack of `[]` is important. With `[]` means to create a module, without means to retrieve an existing module.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Cawley. If I remove the [], then when the initial page loads, no controls are loaded and I get the below error: SCRIPT5022: [$injector:nomod] Module 'testApp.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=testApp.controllers
File: angular.js, Line: 2075, Column: 11

Comment: Okay, that's actually good news, a step in the right direction (because it means that you've renamed your module), now change your `ng-app` directive to be `ng-app="testApp"` in your index.html

Comment: Hi @Matthew Cawley , i already have the below line: <html lang="en" data-framework="angularjs" ng-app="testApp">

Comment: Your error is suggesting that you've still got a reference to `testApp.controllers` hanging about somewhere. Make sure that you only have one `ng-app` directive and that all occurrences of `testApp.controllers` and `testApp.services` are renamed to `testApp`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the result of including any of your app javascript file before the *angularjs* file.

Make sure you include angularjs file before the rest of your app files.

Comment: Hi @Claudia. Angular.js file is loaded first, before the custom js files are loaded.

Comment: Do you declare `testAPIService` on the line where it's stated `testAPIService.getDataSummary = function () {` or before like `testAPIService = {}` and then you go to the line mentioned before. I mean, the code you posted is the full code of your factory?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, who is `testAPIService` at the moment of assigning `getDataSummary` property to it? It must have been declared before.Am I right?

Comment: Hi @claudia. I have other methods as well, so I gave only the portion hitting it. The api service is declared as  var testAPIService = {}; and then followed by the method. I have updated my initial code